# How can I extend a genric parameter with a generic parameter in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a type that I am repeating a lot but with only very small differences:

```
import { ComponentPropsWithRef, ElementType } from "react";

interface PackshotPropsBase {
  a: string
}

interface PackshotPropsWeb {
  b: string
}

export type ElementAndPackshotProps<T extends ElementType, P extends PackshotPropsBase> = Omit<
    ComponentPropsWithRef<T>,
    keyof P
> &
    P;

export type ElementAndPackshotPropsWeb<T extends ElementType, P extends PackshotPropsWeb> = Omit<
    ComponentPropsWithRef<T>,
    keyof P
> &
    P;
```

The only difference is the type that `P` extends. To avoid duplication, how can I create a type where P extends another genric type?

TypeScript playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAFKCMAZwHVgYALAJSwDMAaOAUQBssQcYAVATzCxwAvnDqEQcAERQsAQwDGMSQG4AUKuC4sUOgsF4FAa2KUI%20QiQBCs4oISq4cWQC44xGFE0BzVUPWaYbV15fSMTMwIiMiwAI0QHOBjXd08MHz9VLAAPSFg4GH5BNg4uAEEMABMDeWNTcyiAHm44bMDK4hZ2Tlw%20ASY8Fqy2io7q2oiLYmtbAD44AF44AHkQCgaEx1R0bFxIknIqWjommYYNuEMsXgg6ODxVOYAyc7w1TJzoeAKBTpLccqqYTqe2iMSag2GHWK3R4hX6EJwIzuQImUVIsTmixWa3OW0gO3q%20woNHoJzOjkcl2ut3uTxeyiAA).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue and only your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. There should be no pseudocode, typos, undeclared or unimported types or values, etc.

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAFKCMAZwHVgYALAJSwDMAaOAUQBssQcYAVATzCxwAvnDqEQcAERQsAQwDGMSQG4AUKuC4sUOgsF4FAa2KUI+QiQBCs4oISq4cWQC44xGFE0BzVUPWaYbV15fSMTMwIiMiwAI0QHOBjXd08MHz9VLAAPSFg4GH5BNg4uAEEMABMDeWNTcyiAHm44bMDK4hZ2Tlw+ASY8Fqy2io7q2oiLYmtbAD44AF44AHkQCgaEx1R0bFxIknIqWjommYYNuEMsXgg6ODxVOYAyc7w1TJzoeAKBTpLccqqYTqe2iMSag2GHWK3R4hX6EJwIzuQImUVIsTmixWa3OW0gO3q+woNHoJzOjkcl2ut3uTxeyiAA

Comment: Could you also put that in plaintext in the question post itself?  SO questions should be self-contained and not require navigating away in order to see the full question.

Comment: Sure, have done

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJy65m), but I don't see it buying you anything unless you *always* just use `ElementAndPackshotPropsGeneral`.  TypeScript doesn't have  higher kinded types, so there's no way to write `type Foo<T> = type Bar<U extends T> = U`.  Does this fully address your question (and I can write up an answer) or am I missing something?

Comment: "Sure, have done"... well, no, you put a link to an external site in the question.  I was asking you to put the full example code as plaintext in the question post itself, so that nobody needs to go elsewhere to see the question.  Playground links are great, but they are *supplementary*.  If you don't mind, I could [edit] your question to do this myself.  Let me know.

Comment: Thanks very much, I have updated the question with the code and yes, that explains it perfectly and fully addresses the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, TypeScript lacks *higher kinded types* (as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)), so there's no simple way to write a higher-order generic type that evaluates to a generic type.  That is, nothing like the following works:

```
// INVALID TYPESCRIPT, DON'T DO THIS:

type ElementAndPackshotPropsGeneral<PB> = // error!!
  type<T extends ElementType, P extends PB> = 
    Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof P> & P; 

type ElementAndPackshotProps = 
  ElementAndPackshotPropsGeneral<PackshotPropsBase>;

type ElementAndPackshotPropsWeb = 
  ElementAndPackshotPropsGeneral<PackshotPropsWeb>;
```

Instead, the best you could do is something like this:

```
type ElementAndPackshotPropsGeneral<PB, T extends ElementType, P extends PB> =
  Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof P> & P;

type ElementAndPackshotProps<T extends ElementType, P extends PackshotPropsBase> =
  ElementAndPackshotPropsGeneral<PackshotPropsBase, T, P>;

type ElementAndPackshotPropsWeb<T extends ElementType, P extends PackshotPropsWeb> =
  ElementAndPackshotPropsGeneral<PackshotPropsWeb, T, P>;
```

That works, but you are forced to use "regular" generic types, re-declare the generic type parameters (with their constraints) and pass them through.  While you don't have to write `Omit<ComponentPropsWithRef<T>, keyof P> & P` multiple times, you still have some duplication.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAFKCMAZwHVgYALAJSwDMAaOAUQBssQcYAVATzCxwAvnDqEQcAERQsAQwDGMSQG4AUKuC4sUOgsF4FAa2KUI+QiQBCs4oISq4cWQC44xGFE0BzVUPWaYbV15fSMTMwIiMiwAI0QHOBjXd08MHz91AHpMuHlZDAByeAATCDgqYGJnVUyAKhqcgEkAOQA1AEEAGUaAEThuAE08ZgBlZGpGvG4mHoB5ZoLuODn+gAlGkerVGH5BNg4udoxig3ljU3MogHEcbVlWAB48SwA+OABeOASdgQelrAAHoFjsQWOxOLg+AImHg4IDgcVQc83p8Eo5ZiAKA9UOhsLhIiRyFRaHQ-i8mIYsLwIHQ4Hg3gAyOlqba7MEHXBHE5hC4E0Goxz7CEwLmnc4RCzEG7YKD3J48iVRay2F4sn57cGHY5i8KXQmxD5fQWaznahV6qW3WWPHW8yWkWKq1S1TLqdXs4Wi8186V3G2WJj-IE4REerhQrAwuHBkF014fBIYrE4yB4i1Emj0MkUqk0umM5lutlCrXcs66vl-aMI0ElyG7KPwkNI72S5VYFEJOsis3lu3XK1y22Kqw2SP9GFO1kCMOmsvi9OxKtN2PdiONmOh4eLmKd40cnvziuS33W+V9kfRGKBycsoA)